# How to repeat my program without duplicating

Tags: python, python-3.6

I tried to find out how to repeat my program(code) without duplicating but all of the answers I've read didn't make sense. So can somebody please help me?
This is the program that I was working on

```
import random
words=['hello','run','apple','day','month','cat','dog','bird','car','water']
word=random.choice(words)
length=len(word)
life=50
print('\t\tGuess the word!')
print('instructions: Guess the word. The word is only written by the alphabets.')
pn=input('Type your player name :')
print('Use this to help you! :',words)
print('The length of the word is',length,'letters')
fl=input('Guess the first letter of the word! :')
if fl==word[0]:
    print('Whoah! Nice guess',pn)
else:
    life=life-1
    print('Nice guess but wrong. Try again! You have',life,'lives left!')
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about loops?

Comment: What part of those answers didn't make sense? most likely you'll just receive the same answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a while loop which has a perpetual True condition

just adding **while(True):** to the code will make that snippet to run for ever...

```
import random

while(True):
    words=['hello','run','apple','day','month','cat','dog','bird','car','water']
    word=random.choice (words)
    length=len(word)
    life=50
    print('\t\tGuess the word!')
    print('instructions: Guess the word. The word is only written by the alphabets.')
    pn=input('Type your player name :')
    print('Use this to help you! :',words)
    print('The length of the word is',length,'letters')
    fl=input('Guess the first letter of the word! :')
    if fl==word[0]:
        print('Whoah! Nice guess',pn)
    else:
        life=life-1
        print('Nice guess but wrong. Try again! You have',life,'lives left!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but you could maybe add a boolean correct or not and use a while loop to continue looping till a correct answer was given. 
Something like thus maybe:

```
while incorrect:
    run
    loop
answer is correct
```

The code inside the loop should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
import random

life=50
words=['hello','run','apple','day','month','cat','dog','bird','car','water']
print('\t\tGuess the word!')
print('instructions: Guess the word. The word is only written by the alphabets.')
pn=input('Type your player name :')
print('Use this to help you! : {0}'.format(words))

while life:
    word=random.choice(words)
    length=len(word)
    print('The length of the word is {0} letters'.format(length))
    fl=input('Guess the first letter of the word! :')
    if fl==word[0]:
        print('Whoah! Nice guess {0}'.format(pn))
    else:
        life=life-1
        print('Nice guess but wrong. Try again! You have {0} lives left!'.format(life))
```